# GnuCOBOL not finding routines in a lib file

Tags: windows, cobol, gnucobol

I am running GnuCOBOL on Windows from command line to compile and link a COBOL program. I have been able to produce a functioning Hello World program.
The COBOL program I now want to build is quite simple, but calls routines that are available in a C library I have built using another build environment. I have exchanged some names and paths for anonymity.

The lib is called mysrc.lib, and is placed at C:\dev\foo. I compile and link with the command

```
cobc -x -fword-continuation=ok -ffold-call=LOWER c:\test\MULTI\cobsim.cob -o c:\test\MULTI\cobsim.EXE -LC:\dev\foo -lmysrc
```

It seems to find the lib file, because if I change the name of the lib file to something that doesn't exist, it complains about not finding it.

```
cobc -x -fword-continuation=ok -ffold-call=LOWER  c:\test\MULTI\cobsim.cob -o c:\test\MULTI\cobsim.EXE -LC:\dev\foo -lmysrc2
C:\GnuCOBOL\bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmysrc2
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

However, when I run the program, it cannot find the routines in mysrc. The first C routine in mysrc that is called from the program cobsim.cob is named dbadr4. When I try to run the resulting cobsim.exe, I get the following error:

```
libcob: module 'DBADR4' not found
```

I can also use the flag -fstatic-call to get the link error already when linking.

```
cobc -x -fword-continuation=ok -ffold-call=LOWER -fstatic-call c:\test\MULTI\cobsim.cob -o c:\test\MULTI\cobsim.EXE -LC:\dev\foo -lmysrc
    .\cob14860_0.o:cob14860_0.c:(.text+0x14f): undefined reference to `dbadr4'
```

It doesn't seem to matter which order I place the switches and arguments. Including or excluding the -ffold-call=LOWER flag has no effect, apart from the link error complaining about not finding the routine in upper or lower case. I have multiple other programs calling these routines without problem, including C programs and this specific COBOL program compiled and linked with another compiler and linker on another platform.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: Adding requested information.
Output when adding -g -v flags (some information removed or altered for anonymity):

```
cobc (GnuCOBOL) 3.0-rc1.0
Built     May 05 2018 21:41:43  Packaged  Apr 22 2018 22:26:37 UTC
C version (MinGW) "6.3.0"
loading standard configuration file 'default.conf'
command line:   cobc -x -save-temps -fword-continuation=ok -ffold-call=LOWER -fstatic-call -L C:\dev\foo -l mysrc -o C:\test\MULTI\cobsim.EXE -g -v C:\test\MULTI\cobsim.cob
preprocessing:  C:\test\MULTI\cobsim.cob -> cobsim.i
return status:  0
parsing:        cobsim.i (C:\test\MULTI\cobsim.cob)
return status:  0
translating:    cobsim.i -> cobsim.c (C:\test\MULTI\cobsim.cob)
executing:      gcc -c -I"C:\GnuCOBOL\include"  -g  -o "cobsim.o" "cobsim.c"
return status:  0
executing:      gcc -Wl,--export-all-symbols -Wl,--enable-auto-import
            -Wl,--enable-auto-image-base -o "C:\test\MULTI\cobsim.EXE"
            "cobsim.o" -L"C:\GnuCOBOL\lib"
            -L"C:\dev\foo" -L/mingw/lib
            -lcob -lm -lgmp -L/mingw/lib -lintl -lpdcurses -l"mysrc"
cobsim.o: In function `simple_':
cobsim.c:112: undefined reference to `dbadr4'
```

And snippets of the program code, including the call to dbadr4:

```
       DATA DIVISION.
       WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.

       01 SQL005.
           05 SQL005-001 PIC X(1)  VALUE " ".
       01 SQLPAA.
           05 SQLPAA-001 USAGE POINTER.
           05 SQLPAA-002 USAGE POINTER.
           05 SQLPAA-003 USAGE POINTER.
           05 SQLPAA-004 USAGE POINTER.

       PROCEDURE DIVISION.
       MAIN SECTION.

       DO-IT.
           CALL "DBADR4" USING SQLPAA-001 SQL005
```

EDIT 2: Missed adding the DBADR4 function declaration.

```c
    void dbadr4(void** addr, const int varibl[1])
```

The COBOL code is originally Embedded SQL/COBOL code, the call to DBADR4 and the SQL005 and SQLPAA data blocks have been automatically generated. The dbadr4 code is originally Ada code, the C routine declaration has been automatically generated. This generated COBOL code calling this generated C code works fine on HP OpenVMS, where we use HP's COBOL compiler and linker, and has done so for many years.

Comment: I have updated the question with the requested information.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I completely forgot. Added it now.

Comment: Looks like `CALL "dbadr4" USING SQLPAA-001 SQL005 RETURNING OMITTED` is more appropriate, but I _guess_ the issue is mostly because of how the library was prepared. You do have an `external` in the DBADR4 function declaration, don't you?

Comment: Yes, dbadr4 is declared as external. I'll follow your advice and look into using the same compiler and linker for both dbadr4 and the generated c file from GnuCOBOL.